# Google Maps JavaScript API error: ExpiredKeyMapError

Tags: google-maps

I'm getting the error on the website Google API, so why happening is api not free or whats wrong even I enable the google javascript. Google Maps JavaScript API error: ExpiredKeyMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#expired-key-map-error

Comment: No, the API is not free (but you get a credit). What questions do you have on the text for the error? Did you read the documentation about the key system?

Comment: Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#expired-key-map-error) given on the error message, you usually get ExpiredKeyMapError when the API key you are using is not recognized by the system or already expired.

I suggest generating a new API key and using that new API key in your implementation instead. You can check the youtube tutorial - [How to generate and restrict API keys for Google Maps Platform](https://youtu.be/2_HZObVbe-g)

If the error still persists, I suggest that you [file a support case](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case) to Google Maps Support for further assistance.